# visual studio 2017 change font in sql server object explorer view data grid

Tags: visual-studio

I know this is not a coding question but it greatly impacts my work flow.
I can change the font size in a SQL Results grid in options:Fonts:SQL Results - Grid.
But if you right click a table in the SQL Server Object Explorer and choose "View Data" it opens up a very useful grid with editable data.
But the font is too small on a 4k monitor and I have tried what seems like every single font setting and cannot find it.

Anybody know?

Comment: anybody care to share why they have downvoted this seemingly useful question?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that changing the font under SQL Results - Grid does update this, however, unlike almost all other font changes it does NOT update dynamicly.  Meaning any tabs you have open do not change, you must close them down and then rerun the query.